# How can I re-order this array based on it's translated values?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of Wordpress page parent IDs which I then use a `FOREACH` loop to replace each parent ID with the name of the page (parent).

The problem is the array is sorted by the ID order, and I Want to now re-order it using the titles.

How can I do this?

```
function bv_quick_select_get_category_options() {
    $procedure_pages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php'
            )
        )
    ));
    $procedure_categories = array();
    foreach($procedure_pages as $p1) {
        array_push($procedure_categories, wp_get_post_parent_id($p1->ID));
    }
    $output = '';
    foreach(array_unique($procedure_categories) as $c) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.get_post($c)->post_title.'">'.get_post($c)->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be more efficient to fetch the categories with one query based on the ids, and do the sorting by title in the database. This is my best attempt at how to do that from a quick read of the wordpress docs, but I'm not a wordpress user so it probably needs some work.

```
function bv_quick_select_get_category_options() {
    $procedure_pages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'template-procedure-minimal.php'
            )
        )
    ));

    $ids = array_column($procedure_pages, 'ID');

    $categories = get_posts([
        'include' => $ids,
        'order_by' => 'title'
    ]);

    $output = '';
    foreach($categories as $c) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$c->post_title.'">'.$c->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```